# What is $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} (2^{ki})$?

Tags: summation, geometric-progressions

What is the result of $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n}(2^{ki})$

Is it $\frac{1-2^{kn}}{1-2^k}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you elaborate on how you got to that answer?

Comment: Note that $2^{ki}= (2^k)^i$.  You should recognize $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^i$ as a geometric series which has well known results.  Replacing $x$ by $2^k$ yields the result.

Comment: It should be $\frac{1-2^{k(n+1)}}{1-2^k}$, provided that $k$ is not zero.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: $\dfrac{2^k \left(2^{k n}-1\right)}{2^k-1}$

Comment: You committed what's known as *off by one error*. An easy way to spot those is to test your (guessed) formula for some small values of the parameter. Let's see. When $n=1$ the sum is $2^0+2^k$, but $(1-2^{kn})/(1-2^k)=(1-2^k)/(1-2^k)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k} &= \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \right) \, x^{k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k+n+1} \\
&= \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x}
\end{align}
then
for $x = t^{m}$ it is given that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} t^{m \, k} = \frac{1 - t^{m \, (n+1)}}{1 - t^{m}}.$$
Letting $t = 2$ provides the result in question.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}2^{ki}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(2^k)^i=\frac{(2^k)^{n+1}-1}{2^k-1}=\frac{2^{kn+k}-1}{2^k-1}$$